# MemoryError while converting sparse matrix to dense matrix? (numpy, scikit)

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn

```
lr = lm.LogisticRegression(penalty='l2', dual=True, tol=0.0001, 
                             C=1, fit_intercept=True, intercept_scaling=1.0, 
                             class_weight=None, random_state=None)

rd = AdaBoostClassifier( base_estimator=lr, 
                                           learning_rate=1, 
                                           n_estimators=20, 
                                           algorithm="SAMME")
##here, i am deleting unnecesseary objects
##print X.shape
##(7395, 412605)
print "20 Fold CV Score: ", np.mean(cross_validation.cross_val_score(rd, X, y, cv=20, scoring='roc_auc'))
```

When i run this i get this error:

> TypeError: A sparse matrix was passed, but dense data is required. Use
>   X.toarray() to convert to a dense numpy array.

And then, i changed my code like this:

```
print "20 Fold CV Score: ", np.mean(cross_validation.cross_val_score(rd, X.toarray(), y, cv=20, scoring='roc_auc'))
```

Now, i have the following exception:

```
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/sparse/compressed.py", line 559, in toarray
    return self.tocoo(copy=False).toarray(order=order, out=out)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/sparse/coo.py", line 235, in toarray
    B = self._process_toarray_args(order, out)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/sparse/base.py", line 628, in _process_toarray_args
    return np.zeros(self.shape, dtype=self.dtype, order=order)
MemoryError
```

Any suggestions to solve the issue?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`MemoryError` means that there isn't enough RAM available on your system to allocate the matrix. Why? Well, a `7395 x 412605` matrix has 3,051,213,975 elements. If they're in the default `float64` (usually `double` in C) datatype, that's 22.7GB. If you convert to lower-precision `float32`s (usually `float` in C), it'd be 11.4GB; maybe that's handle-able on your machine. It'll still be real slow, though.

It seems that `AdaBoostClassifier` doesn't support sparse inputs (as you can see [in the code here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/ensemble/weight_boosting.py#L93)). I don't know offhand if dense representations are necessary for the algorithm or if it's just that the implementation assumed that.

Comment: It's the implementation. Sparse matrix support for decision trees, and therefore all the fancy ensemble estimators, has been on the todo list for a very long time.